# Custom xorg.conf in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: xorg, 16.04

Unluckily my monitor not correctly recognized by Xorg and it has never been so the very first thing I always do after a new install is to copy my custom xorg.conf to the directory `/etc/X11`. It is very basic and looks like

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "asus"
    Vendorname  "Asus"
    Modelname   "VW198S"
    Modeline    "1680x1050" 147.600 1680 1784 1968 2256 1050 1051 1054 1087 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "asus"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
    SubSection "Display"
       Depth    24
       Modes    "1680x1050"
    EndSubSection
 EndSection
```

This does not work any longer in 16.04: what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 5):

The new location seems to be:

```
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf
```

Not sure if that will help though.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I needed to provide a custom EDID file for my TV to work. I took my old 14.04 xorg.conf backup (because xorg.conf was deleted in the upgrade), put relevant config into /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/ and then everything worked properly again.