# Screen refresh / repaint issues with Ubuntu MATE both 16.04 and 18.04

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, screen, mate

I am using two different Lenovo laptops and even two different Ubuntu-MATE versions 16.04 and 18.04, yet ever since I started with Ubuntu, I suffer refresh / repaint problems (on a multitude of monitors and docking stations, so let's not blame those...)

[image: screen photo]

If I switch to the next workspace (virtual screens) and back, these artifacts are gone. If I move a window slowly over it, it's also gone. Basically most things triggering a repaint makes it gone. Hastily shaking windows around tends to create them.

I know little about Linux & hardware, but let me share what I know. I appear to have intel graphics:

```
$> sudo lspci|grep VGA
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

And DRI2 (what that was again?)

```
$> xdpyinfo | grep DRI
    DRI2
```

My [xorg config](https://askubuntu.com/questions/765195/custom-xorg-conf-in-ubuntu-16-04) (if I am not talking gibberish) does **not** seem to contain a `20-intel.conf`...

```
$> cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
10-amdgpu.conf            10-quirks.conf            11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  50-vmmouse.conf           51-synaptics-quirks.conf
10-evdev.conf             11-evdev-quirks.conf      50-synaptics.conf         50-wacom.conf
```

Not sure, what to make of that `10-amdgpu.conf` file (Didn't I have intel graphics?)

```
cat /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-amdgpu.conf
Section "OutputClass"
        Identifier "AMDgpu"
        MatchDriver "amdgpu"
        Driver "amdgpu"
```

Is this `usr/share`-xorg.conf.d just an *overlay* of settings, and the basic, core conf is elsewhere? Should I possible creatre a `20-intel.conf` as [suggest here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_graphics#Troubleshooting).

Or is the problem somewhere else entirely?
**I am totally cluessless on these matters.**